# Full-screen camera

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I make the iPhone camera full-screen by removing the overlay?

Can I change the camera toolbar style?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way to do this using the current iPhone SDK. You should file a [bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple to try to get them to add more control over the camera.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a blog on this last night, that discussed how to stripp out the overlay view.

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/10/creating-a-full-screen-camera.html

It's not clear whether this would pass testing, though Phanfare do customize their view.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this for quite some time.

Aswell as the link in the post above mine. I've stumbled across this page - http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/11/views-of-uiimagepickercontroller/

While the article itself is not spectacular, the comments provide some great insight and suggestions. Also, some users provided links to some external sites. If you happen to get it working, please email me.